# How can I set the timezone to New York with python MySQL Connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I use an SQL server on siteground that I need to be set to New York / America EST.  The server is locked at UTC.

I communicate with the server via a script with the python mysql.connector library.

I need to change the timezone to this New York time every connection.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
arbitrage_db = mysql.connector.connect(  # connecting to arbing db
    host="your host",
    user="username",
    password="password",
    database="database"
    )
cursor = arbitrage_db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT NOW()')
for time in cursor:
    print(time)
print()
arbitrage_db.time_zone = "-04:00"
cursor.execute('SELECT NOW()')
for time in cursor:
    print(time)
cursor.close()
arbitrage_db.close()
```